# Is there a way to include timed pauses while looping through an array?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am creating an app that can translate letters in a string to a vibration pattern. Here is what I have so far:

```
@IBAction func translateButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
   guard CHHapticEngine.capabilitiesForHardware().supportsHaptics else {return}

let Bz1 = CHHapticEvent(eventType: .hapticContinuous, parameters: [], relativeTime: 0.0, duration: 0.1)
let Bz2 = CHHapticEvent(eventType: .hapticContinuous, parameters: [], relativeTime: 0.3, duration: 0.1)
let Bzz1 = CHHapticEvent(eventType: .hapticContinuous, parameters: [], relativeTime: 0.0, duration: 0.25)

let dictionary = [
"A" : [Bzz1],
"T" : [Bz1, Bz2],
]

let message = detectedTextLabel.text
//text box where string is written

let letterArray = message!.map { String($0) }

 for singleWord in letterArray {

    let word = String(singleWord)
    if let vibrationArray = dictionary[word] {

    do {

      for Word in vibrationArray {

           let encodedMessage = try CHHapticPattern(events: [Word], parameters: [])
           let player = try engine?.makePlayer(with: encodedMessage)
           try player?.start(atTime: 0)

    }
     } catch {
       print("there was an error")
     }

     } else {
      print("There was an error")
      }

 }
```

So far, this code works if I type singular letters into the text box. However, as an example, if I type "AT" in the text box, instead of the vibrations playing one after another, they both play at the same time. Is there a way to put some kind of delay or pause between the first letter pattern and the second letter pattern?

Comment: Did you try sleep() function ?

Comment: I have. It brought up an error said that the CHHapticEvent is not compatible with a sleep function

Comment: try  this : Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { _ in
        // Do your stuff here
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would convert it from a for...in loop to a traditional C-style for loop so that you can keep track of the indices. Then when inside the for loop, you can wrap everything in a DispatchQueue delay based on the current index of the letter you're on. Something like this.

```
for i in 0..<letterArray.count {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(i*1)) {
        // put current for loop code inside here
    }
}
```

This just assumes a delay of 1 second. You can also use Swift's [enumerated()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687832-enumerated) if you prefer.

```
for (index, singleWord) in letterArray.enumerated() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(index * 1)) {
        // put current for loop code inside here
    }
}
```

Comment: This works exactly how I needed it to! Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to have helped! The enumerated way is probably best for your case, I just didn't think of it right away.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Timer for making Delay

```swift
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { _ in // Do your stuff here }
```